# SAMBA | Different network interface for specific directories

Tags: networking, server, samba

I've an Ubuntu server 22.04 with samba installed which has 2 physical ethernet connections. On that server I have multiple shared folders and I would like to have folders A, B & C available on interface 1 and folders C, D & E available on interface 2.

I tried to follow the samba wiki tutorial about multiple samba instances, but as it's for RedHat it has some differencies that I'm not good enough to pass.
Could be perfect to put the 'interface' line inside the folder spec instead of global one.

Is someone acheive to split shared folders on differents interfaces?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670347/can-i-bind-to-specific-interface-for-different-samba-shares ?

Comment: Hi. Both IP must be on the same subnet, so I can't use 'Allow hosts' option due to we all have the same netmask. To be simple, we have two 'identities' with same shared-folders constructions (client - management - ressources - ... ) and 2 shared folder accessible for both identities. And in our team we have workers who work for both sides.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to acheive it. Following this method [linuxtopia - Virtual server](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/network_administration_guides/samba_reference_guide/41_cfgsmarts_05.html)

> In the smb.conf file, we can add a parameter %i which is the IP called by the client. Be sure to have yours interfaces specified inside the conf file. Then, use 'include = smb-%i.conf' inside the smb.conf *(it will be the master conf file, with all general settings and common shared folders if needed)*. Finally, make 2 *(or more if you have more interfaces)* files called smb-ip-of-the-server.conf with the special shared folders and specific global parameter.

I still try to make it works with the netbios name and netbios aliases but it seems to not work if I enter 'smb ports = 139' inside the conf file. If I do, no more acces to the smb server, even if I comment the line with # at the line start...

EDIT: netbios seems to be a dead end for me. I'm trying to use DHCP or DNS to map a hostname to the server network interface. Modifiying the windows hosts file in the client works perfectly but I don't want to make it for all devices. I'm looking for a router level or server level solution.

EDIT 2: Netbios ports were blocked in my router's firewall by default... So I finally used a DNS attribution inside the router options *(server1.srv for ip1 and server2.srv for ip2)* and it seams to work perfectly.
Hope that could help someone.